# Pass multiple variables to function, right syntax?

Tags: jquery, variables

I want to pass several variables to a function, but my solution is not working. (hope I used the right terms)
Here is an example:

```
function newFunc(color) {

   console.log('my fav color is' + color)

} newFunc('blue', 'black', 'green');
```

I want to get three console entries.

```
my fav color is blue
my fav color is black
my fav color is green
```

What's the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add **all** the parameters to your function as well

```js
//all parameters
function newFunc(var1, var2, var3) 
{
   console.log(var1);
   console.log(var2);
   console.log(var3);
} 
//add the parameters when calling the function
newFunc('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
```

If you have a lot of parameters you could pass an array instead

```js
//add as many parameters as you need
var yourArray = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5','var6','var7','var8','var9','var10'];
newFunc(yourArray);

//all parameters
function newFunc(parameter) 
{
  //iterate through array
  for( var i = 0; i < parameter.length; i++ )
  {
      //output each element in the array
      console.log(parameter[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to achieve the same effect with just on variable? i edited my original question to be more precise

Comment: @user3439585 Sure, check my updated answer. You could pass an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function newFunc (name1, name2, name3) {
    ...
}
```

Name the variables to reflect what data they should contain.  You may have an issue with naming the variable 'var' as it's a key word in javascript.

Alternatively, you can reference the `arguments` variable which is an array which will contain all the passed in arguments, no matter if they were on the function definition or not.  But you should use the parameters as much as possible for clarity.